# Fix multiple jquery libraries

Tags: jquery

so i am trying to implement two different scripts using different versions of jquery.
The first one uses 1.3.2:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script1a.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script1b.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script1c.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script1d.js"></script>
```

The second one uses 1.5.1:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slides.min.jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#slides').slides({
```

When loading the 1.5.1 the first script doesnt work anymore and the other way around.
I tried to use:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>  

 var $ = jQuery.noConflict();  

</script>
```

And i tried this and changes all $ of the following script to jq151:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>  

 var jq151 = jQuery.noConflict();  

</script>
```

Can somebody help me with this? I didnt write those scripts those were free templates from the web, i cant really code jquery i just copy and alter it so it does fit for my site but i am just stuck on this conflict. Would really appreciate it!

Comment: can u provide script code where u getting problem coz both newer version supports most of the function of older version. so I guess ur problem can be solved by changing some of the code only.Also `jQuery.noConfict` is used when u are using more than one library which use same `$` sign to work with

Answer (score 4):

http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page/

Comment: is there a difference if i change $ to $jq or to jq151? its still just a name of a variable right? also i tried $jq already and it didnt work. so are you sure that works a 100%? i will try it again maybe i did a mistake somewhere..

Comment: i tried to come up with a work around as my site doesnt need to be nice coded, so i used an iframe but that doesnt work because my main script makes use of the mouse coordinates wich is not working when hovering the iframe area.

Comment: ok i cleaned up my whole code and took only the first jquery version and the script wich works. then i changed the $ to jqfix by search and replace in every .js i have including the library. doesnt work.. anything i should know when changing $?

Comment: I have to admit, that i hadn't such issues in big projects, but you have to get rid of the $ function in all old code and it should work. everything which uses version 1.5 should be using the var jq15 and everything which uses version 1.6 should then  use the var jq16 and only the actual one should use the $ function. if you got problems please post your code with http://jsfiddle.net/ or on another webpage :) And please look also here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/